# Displaying a WordPress JSONP blog post title in angular-ui ui-calendar

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, fullcalendar, jsonp, angular-ui

I'm new to angular, so apologies if this has an obvious answer. I want to display a blog post title and its published date, as the start date, on the ui-calendar. It works fine with hardcoded start, end and title values but nothing is returned when in the success directive when I make a jsonp call.

The jsonp call works fine if I don't use the calendar, so I think it's a syntax issue.

This is my angular code (with hard-coded dates):

```js
var MyController = function($scope) {

    $scope.uiConfig = {
        ...
    };

$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];

$scope.events = [
                    {
                        start  : '2015-04-20',
                        end    : '2015-04-21',
                        type: "GET",
                        url: 'http://calendar.jacarandatech.com/wp-json/posts/5/?_jsonp=?',
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        success: function(response) {
                            //what do I put here to display the response.title??
                        }
                    }
                ]
};

angular
    .module('MyApp', ['ui'])
    .controller('MyController', MyController);
```

and my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.1/angular-1.0.1.js" ng:autobind></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.dillingermediaonline.com/angular-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

    <title>ng calendar</title>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-controller="MyController" calendar="calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

jsonp code (works fine):

```js
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://calendar.jacarandatech.com/wp-json/posts/5/?_jsonp=?',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (response) {
            var posttitle = response.title;
            var timestamp = response.modified_gmt;
            console.log('post title = ' + posttitle);
            console.log('timestamp = ' + timestamp);
        }
});
```

I researched the following stackoverflow questions but couldn't get their solutions to work:
[How do I use jsonp with angular-ui calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350601/how-do-i-use-jsonp-with-angular-ui-calendar)

[Angular JSONP calling WordPress JSON REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598306/angular-jsonp-calling-wordpress-json-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the variables that contain the title and the timestamp are within the controller's scope.

First, in the first line add `$http` in the controller like this:

```
var MyController = function($scope, $http) {
```

then declare the variables:

```
$scope.postTitle = '';
$scope.postTimestamp = '';
```

You should use `$http` to make the AJAX call. The other function you showed is not needed.

```
$http.get('http://calendar.jacarandatech.com/wp-json/posts/5/?_jsonp=?').success(function (res) {
                $scope.postTitle = res.title;
                $scope.postTimestamp = res.modified_gmt;
            });
```

This will let you declare the calendar event like this:

```
start  : $scope.postTimestamp,
title    : $scope.postTitle
```